# Paypal Plus not show in Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

Paypal plus is not showing if I add a gift code. If there is no gift code applied, then it shows fine.

How can I fix it?

it shows below error:

```
{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":
[{"field":"transactions[0].amount","issue":"Amount cannot be zero"},
{"field":"transactions[0].amount","issue":"Transaction amount details 
(subtotal, tax, shipping) must add up to specified amount 
total"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details"
```

If i add 2 products and use giftcode, total = 5,00$. Paypal not work and show error

```
{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":
[{"field":"transactions[0].amount","issue":"Transaction amount details 
(subtotal, tax, shipping) must add up to specified amount 
total"}],"message":"Invalid request - see 
details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors"
,"debug_id":"5d0095b48c028"}
```

Comment: When you apply your gift code, the total becomes zero? the error says so.

Comment: But if i add 2 products to cart, and use giftcode, total = 5,00$, paypal plus not show too ?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal and PayPal Plus will not process transactions when the total amount is zero.

The total amount must always be greater than zero for these payment methods.

Magento has a zero amount payment method you could enable for use in these situations.

Comment: Can I pay with paypal plus when total = 0?

Comment: No. The total amount must always be greater than zero.

Comment: But if i add 2 products to cart, and use giftcode, total = 5,00$, paypal plus not show too ?

Comment: You have two validation problems.  The second is `{"field":"transactions[0].amount","issue":"Transaction amount details 
(subtotal, tax, shipping) must add up to specified amount 
total"}`

Comment: How to fix it? can you help me?

Comment: You need to ensure that the totals of all the line items match up to exactly the total of the transaction. Any deviation will result in the transaction being rejected by both PayPal and PayPal Plus.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue in our shop. For an older Magento-Version we used the Rounding-Bugfix (aka "1-Cent-Bug") by adding two local files

```
app/core/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php
```

and

```
app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php
```

In newer Magento1-Versions (e.g. 1.9.4.3) this bugfix is not necessary anymore BUT if the files are still in place, they will crash your PPP.

If you have used such a bugfix also in your shop, try to remove this files. (Backup first!)